# Can not connect to SSTP VPN Debug out included

Tags: networking, windows, network-manager, vpn

I am unable to get VPN via sstp working. The connection works inside a Windows-VM but not on my ubuntu host.

I'm not sure if my host is even talking to the other side or if the error completely happens on my side.

Authentication is done by certificate, which I configured. I cant connect using command line and also not by using network-manager gui.

I have installed following libs:

```
sstp-client 1.0.12-0ubuntu1
network-manager-sstp 1.2.6-0ubuntu0
libsstp-api-0 1.0.12-0ubuntu1
```

I can offer following config:

```
[vpn]
ca-cert=/home/USR123/.ssh/pfx/vpn.pem
domain=xyz
gateway=123.123.123.123
ignore-cert-warn=yes
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-interval=30
no-vj-comp=yes
nobsdcomp=yes
nodeflate=yes
password-flags=2
proxy-password-flags=0
refuse-chap=yes
refuse-eap=yes
refuse-pap=yes
require-mppe=yes
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sstp

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

And following output with loglevel debug:

```
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7359] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"] MODIFY check result YES
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7610] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent returned secrets for request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7615] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x12345bcaa8f0) secrets returned from agent :1.89
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7616] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x12345bcaa8f0) secrets request completed
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7623] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x12345bcaa8f0) new agent secrets processed
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7627] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: asking service if additional secrets are required
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7636] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: service indicated additional secrets required
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7636] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: requesting VPN secrets pass #3
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7640] Secrets requested for connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3 (sstp/vpn)
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7640] agent-manager: req[0x7f35d4004870, :1.188/nmcli-connect/1000]: agent allowed for secrets request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7640] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent allowed for secrets request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7641] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x56191bd30020) secrets requested flags 0x5 hints '(none)'
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7643] agent-manager: ([0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]) system settings secrets insufficient, asking agents
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7644] agent-manager: req[0x7f35d4004870, :1.188/nmcli-connect/1000]: agent getting secrets for request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7644] agent-manager: ([0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]) request has system secrets; checking agent :1.188 for MODIFY
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7644] auth: call[681]: CheckAuthorization(org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own), subject=unix-process[pid=19967, uid=1000, start=395
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7657] auth: call[681]: CheckAuthorization succeeded: (is_authorized=1, is_challenge=0)
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7657] agent-manager: req[0x7f35d4004870, :1.188/nmcli-connect/1000]: agent [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"] MODIFY check result YES
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7675] agent-manager: req[0x7f35d4004870, :1.188/nmcli-connect/1000]: agent returned no secrets for request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7675] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent getting secrets for request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7675] agent-manager: ([0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]) request has system secrets; checking agent :1.89 for MODIFY
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7675] auth: call[682]: CheckAuthorization(org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own), subject=unix-process[pid=1734, uid=1000, start=7235
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7688] auth: call[682]: CheckAuthorization succeeded: (is_authorized=1, is_challenge=0)
Feb 16 19:11:40 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340700.7688] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"] MODIFY check result YES
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0849] agent-manager: req[0x56191bd351b0, :1.89/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent returned secrets for request [0x56191bd30020/"sstp"/"vpn"]
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0858] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x56191bc66400) secrets returned from agent :1.89
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0858] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x56191bc66400) secrets request completed
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0875] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: (vpn:0x56191bc66400) saving new secrets to backing storage
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0974] ++ connection 'get-new-secrets' (0x56191bc69540/NMSimpleConnection/"vpn" < 0x56191bc1bb60/NMSKeyfileConnection/"vpn"):
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0974] ++ vpn                       [ 0x51234bd7b123 < 0x1234bd1ba55 ]
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0974] ++ vpn.secrets               = ((GHashTable*) 0x7f23a4234b10) < ((GHashTable*) 0x51244bd7b111)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.0984] settings-connection[0x56191bc1bb60,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1]: write: successfully updated (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/s
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.0992] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: asking service if additional secrets are required
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1016] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: service indicated no additional secrets required
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1020] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: Allowing interactive secrets as all agents have that capabilit
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.1029] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1029] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: VPN connection: falling back to non-interactive connect
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.1043] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 pppd[19985]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-sstp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-sstp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 pppd[19985]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 pppd[19985]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 pppd[19985]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1100] platform: signal: link   added: 9: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1500 arp 512 ppp* not-init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1101] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): constructed (NMDevicePpp)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1101] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): start setup of NMDevicePpp, kernel ifindex 9
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1102] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/phys_port_id: error reading 4096 bytes from file descriptor: Vorgang wird nicht unters
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1102] platform-linux: sysctl: reading 'net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/dev_id': '0x0'
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1103] platform-linux: error reading net:/sys/class/net/ppp0/device/sriov_totalvfs: Failed to open file "device/sriov_totalvfs" with openat: Datei 
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1103] platform-linux: do-request-link: 9 
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1103] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down=0x810/0x810/unmanaged/unrealized], set-unmanaged [extern
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1103] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!loopback=0x810/0x818/unmanaged/unrealized], set-managed
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1103] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!sleeping,!loopback=0x810/0x819/unmanaged/unrealized], s
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.1108] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1213] platform-linux: UDEV event: action 'add' subsys 'net' device 'ppp0' (9); seqnum=3988
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1214] platform: signal: link changed: 9: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1500 arp 512 ppp* init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1214] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): queued link change for ifindex 9
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.1215] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1550340705.1215] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1216] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,external-down,!sleeping,!loopback,!user-settings=0x810/0x859/unmanaged
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1216] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unmanaged: flags set to [external-down,!sleeping,!loopback,!platform-init,!user-settings=0x800/0x859/manageab
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1218] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x56191bce7090)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1221] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): ip4-config: set IP4Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/12)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1221] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1221] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1221] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1222] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): ip6-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0x56191bcf0b80)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1225] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): ip6-config: set IP6Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/12)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1225] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1225] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Feb 16 19:11:45 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340705.1225] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 sstpc[19990]: Connection was aborted, Reason was not known
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 pppd[19985]: Modem hangup
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: Modem hangup
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: Connection terminated.
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 pppd[19985]: Connection terminated.
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3168] platform: signal: link removed: 9: ppp0 <NOARP,DOWN;pointopoint,multicast,noarp> mtu 1500 arp 512 ppp* init addrgenmode eui64 driver ppp rx:
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3172] platform: signal: address 4 changed: 192.168.0.5/24 lft 600797sec pref 600797sec lifetime 39568-35566[604799,604799] dev 2 flags noprefixrou
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3172] device[0x56191bcd5460] (enp0s25): queued IP4 config change
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3174] platform: signal: address 6 changed: 2a02:810b:c240:122c:59a4:3f8d:cf8b:93a/64 lft 4717sec pref 2017sec lifetime 39568-39530[2055,4755] dev 
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3175] device[0x56191bcd5460] (enp0s25): queued IP6 config change
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3176] platform: signal: address 6 changed: 2a02:810b:c240:122c:2a16:a257:5791:ee17/64 lft 4717sec pref 2017sec lifetime 39568-39530[2055,4755] dev
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <warn>  [1550340706.3181] vpn-connection[0x56191bd724c0,1a5b2d23-d1a4-4a7e-843b-3ec123c4a6a1,"sstp",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Feb 16 19:11:46 USR123 NetworkManager[981]: <debug> [1550340706.3182] device[0x56191bd59e50] (ppp0): unrealize (ifindex 9)
```